# ImportError: cannot import name 'regression_report' from 'sklearn.metrics'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, importerror

```
 3 from sklearn.metrics import regression_report,confusion_matrix
      4 print(confusion_matrix(y_train,predict_train))
      5 print(Regression_report(y_train,predict_train))

ImportError: cannot import name 'regression_report' from 'sklearn.metrics' (C:\Users\charl\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\__init__.py)
```

I get an error code when trying to import

> from sklearn.metrics import regression_report,confusion_matrix
> print(confusion_matrix(y_train,predict_train))
> print(Regression_report(y_train,predict_train))`

My sklearn version is 1.0.2

Any idea?

Comment: There isn't any function called as regression_report in sklearn. There is only classification_report

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are looking for [`classification_report`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html#sklearn.metrics.classification_report)

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
print(classification_report(y_train, predict_train))
```

Comment: Ah yes, that's where I was running into a problem, thank you!